Standard logic app does not show history after incremental deployment with YAML file from Azure DevOps
I am deploying Logic apps with ARM templates. I am Using those two tasks.
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: "Create Standard Logic Application"
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: $(TestSubscription)
    subscriptionId: $(IDTestSubscription)
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
    location: 'West Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/armtemplates/logicapp_deployment.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/armtemplates/logicapp_parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    deploymentOutputs: 'ArmOutputsLA'
  continueOnError: true

- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: Deploy Logic App Workflows
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(IDTestSubscription)
    appType: functionapp 
    appName: $(LaAppName)
    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/workflow.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
    ResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
  continueOnError: true

Website_Rum_From_Package appsetting is not deployed as a setting.
I want to know how I can get back the run history after a incremental deployment has taken place. Is there a way to do that?

I found the issue and applied the solution.
The deployment took place with a unique Website_ContentShare (Fileshare name) in the appsettings from the ARM template. I replaced the unique number with the name of the logic app that is being deployed, so this will always be unique also.
Instead of:
{
   "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
   "value": "[variables('uniqueNumber')"
}

I am using:
{
   "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
   "value": "[variables('logicappName')"
}

Now at every deployment the fileshare keeps remaining the same and the run history is available.
